auth 2.0 from Microsoft not redirecting to call back url after successful permission accept
I have the following NodeJS code
async onedrive (
    addon: AddOn,
    app: express.Application,
    req: any,
    res: any
) {
    const storageType = req.query.storageType; // Get the selected storage type from the query parameter
    const selectedScopes = scopes[storageType];
    if (!selectedScopes) {
      return res.status(400).send('Invalid storage type');
    }
    const authUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(selectedScopes)}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI)}&prompt=consent&state=${encodeURIComponent(storageType)}`;
    res.json({ authUrl }); // Send the URL as a JSON response 
}



async callback (
       addon: AddOn,
       app: express.Application,
       req: any,
       res: any
   ) {
       const code = req.query.code; 
       const storageType = req.query.state;   
       // const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'profile_picture.jpg'); // Define the path where you want to save the image
       try {
      
           const selectedScopes = scopes[storageType];
           if (!selectedScopes) {
           return res.status(400).send('Invalid storage type');
           }
           const params = new URLSearchParams();
           params.append('client_id', CLIENT_ID);
           params.append('scope', selectedScopes);
           params.append('redirect_uri', REDIRECT_URI);
           params.append('client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET);
           params.append('code', code);
           params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
   
           // Exchange the authorization code for an access token
           const tokenResponse = await axios.post(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`, params, {
               headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               },
           });
   
           const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
           const refreshToken = tokenResponse.data.refresh_token;
           const expiryDate = tokenResponse.data.expires_in;
           const returnData = {
                   access_token: accessToken,
                   refresh_token: refreshToken,
               };
               var io = req.app.get('socketio');
               var sessionId = req.app.get('sessionId');
               io.to(sessionId).emit("response", returnData);
               res.sendFile(path.resolve("./loginSuccess.html"));
     } 
       catch (error: any) {
           console.error('Error authenticating with OneDrive:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
           res.status(500).send('Authentication failed.');
       }
   }

when i am redirected to get a token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2 i am getting the following admin request approval
i asked my admin and he approved my request but yet nothing happened and i am not being redirected to the callback URL, what may be the issue? am i missing something?
although the call back URL is valid and working from azure side as if i click on go back to app i got the authorization failed message that i am setting


as mentioned in my question: i asked my admin and he approved my request but yet nothing happened and i am not being redirected to the callback URL, and i got the email saying that your request is approved

Did you added Sign-Redirect.js file ? It contains code like  window.location.href = document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv=refresh]").getAttribute("data-url");

where should i add this?

Do you any events when your admin approves your request ? If yes then you need to write inside it.
